# Cleaning date field returned to django view from ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, django, django-forms

EDIT:  My def form_invalid of the `class ProviderUpdateView(UpdateView):

```
  def form_invalid(self, form):
    print("form is invalid")
    print(form.errors)
    return HttpResponse("form is invalid.. this is just an HttpResponse object")
```

I might open a second question to figure out why this isn't rendering on the form and yet some 'must fill out this field is' might have to do with crispy forms not sure I didn't write this part and have to look into it :/

I have a date field that comes across in the data field of an ajax call.   I can get the data just fine in my views.py

```
dateJ = request.GET.get('date_joined_group')
```

This is great, but when I try to throw it into my model it dies everytime.  I need to 'clean' the data, I know my forms when I am just doing standard get post ops works and does this automagically.  Is there a way I can invoke this automagic when not using form stuff but using the ajax call?

I tried this:

```
       dateObj = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(dateJ), '%m-%d-%Y')
```

Then in my model:

```
grpProvInfo.date_joined_group = dateObj    
grpProvInfo.save()
```

This worked, till I used the date picker on the form which put it in as 4/29/2009

So the slashes broke my 'slick fix', gotta be an easier way then trying to account for all the possibilities just not sure how to invoke it from a little def method I have for the ajax call in my python.

Comment: The easiest way would be to modify the string before it comes in or modify the string when it gets to you with something like this. `dateJ.replace('/', '-')`

Comment: This works decently, I have to figure out how to validate on the javascript side and send the errors to the form which is all built in django :(

Comment: Don't do that. The form itself should be able to accept multiple formats via the field's [`input_formats` attribute](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#datefield).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So there are a few different python libraries that can help you in a big way.  This one, [dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), lets you input as many different formats as you'd like to be able to parse, and returns a datetime object.  This would solve your problem with slashes.  Another piece of advice would be to always serve your date in the same format regardless of how it is input.  If you use django forms and the date field, you will automatically get validation (of a valid date string), and that combined with dateparser should allow you to safely parse any date string.

And for simplicity's sake, you should be able to change the default format of the datepicker. But that's not truly the answer for how to fix your problem

Comment: I think you hit the nail on the head, I do use django forms.  But this form in particular is a modal form that pops up now and again and I use Ajax to send all the data to and from the server.  So it seems to be bypassing the standard validation, or I am missing a step in how I am working with this ajax call.   I could post the code not sure if that would help in this instance though.   I also wish I could validate on the javascript side and any errors make them show up in the form like standard django validation.

Comment: So, for the javascript side, you can write a method that called when a user clicks submit that validates and sends it through if valid, and complains otherwise.  This is basically a wrapper around the ajax. Other than that, django's form should validate correctly regardless of whether it is asynchronous.  You do have a view that specifically handles the async call, correct?

Comment: yes I have a view that handles the call.  I guess I wasn't sure when errors were getting rendered.  I didn't write the form so I am tracking down stuff...for instance looks like it is an unbound form.  Yet it knows when the name on the form is missing and wont save and will say to fill out the field (yet I see required no where).It gave me an idea though, for the javascript to do my own validation and just use jquery to make the errors look pretty if some are found and do a prevent default? or return or something to avoid the submit.  Off to debug the basic errors not showing on the form now:/

Comment: You're seeing that because fields are required by default. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/fields/#required

Comment: ahh okay, and I can get the form to validate my dates but I have to bound the form which if I do crashed on the updateview not the createview so I have to keep tinkering but this gave me some ideas thanks. I will accept the answer.